# Kernel make error: “sorry, unimplemented: -mfloat-abi=hard and VFP”

Tags: kernel, make, android, cross-compilation

I am trying to compile kernel for Allwinner A10 processor (sun4i, ARMV7) for Android 4.1.2. Config file is copied from the device. This is the output :

`$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/user/android_kernel/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: include/generated/mach-types.h is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
kernel/bounds.c:1: sorry, unimplemented: -mfloat-abi=hard and VFP
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2`

The error is the `kernel/bounds.c:1: sorry, unimplemented: -mfloat-abi=hard and VFP`, for which I could not find solution

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your cross compiler? "*The combination of -mfpu=vfp and -mfloat-abi=hard is not available in FSF GCC 4.4*". Shouldn't you configure `-mfpu=neon` as the A10 has an cortex-A8 with NEON?

Comment: I am using gcc version 4.8.4. Do I understand it right that I should change it in the Makefile?

Comment: But the version of arm-linux-androideabi-gcc, with which it is compiling is `gcc version 4.7.3 (Linaro GCC 4.7-2014.01)`.

Comment: Okay, I don't have information about this issue for linaro gcc 4.7, but I would try to find, where `-mfpu=vfp` is set and change it to `neon`. I don't know whether this will solve the problem, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're using a toolchain configured for `softfloat` targets. You'll need a hardware floating point-supported one.

Comment: Thanks! I did : `sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` and used it as `CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-`